# Excel Date&Time vs value plot

Tags: excel, graph, excel-formula, excel-2016, vba

I am working on a dataset that has over 30,000 rows, and I need to create a time-value plot.

My data consists of 4 types of columns

- item
- date[YYYY-MM-DD]
- time[00:00:00]
- simple values

I have 15 names in total, and the values are recorded every 10 minutes for 14 days.

If I want to create a graph that has 15 curves on it with `date&time` on the x-axis and `value` on the y-axis, how should I do it?

I sorted the data with names, date, time, so I could do it manually by selecting the values and Date&time for each item which would be ridiculous. Would creating a Loop in Macro help and how to code it? or is there another way of doing it?

Comment: Please improve your question: `date`, `time` and `value` are 3 columns. not 4. Also press enter TWICE to start a new paragraph and use the buttons to add formatting.

Comment: @DirkHorsten The four columns he stated are `Item`, `date`, `time`, `value`

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data, as something that can be pasted into a worksheet (i.e. **NOT** an image), to make it easier for someone to reproduce your problem. It may be helpful to read HELP for [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @DoeDoe, Thanks for your edits. This imroves the value of your question in our knowledge database. We will reward you reward you by upvoting your question.

Answer (score 0):

Create a pivot table with

- Row fields: `date` and `time`
- Column field: `item`
- Data field: `value`

Create your graph from there.